# How do I tar all files without paths

Tags: linux, find, directory, tar, xargs

I want to find all .c files in current directory and subdirectories and tar them. I try to use the following way to achieve this goal but when i unzip files, the files in different folders. I don't want to include directory when I tar the file.

The script should exclude all other files and should not maintain the directory
structure for these .c files.

```
find . -name '*.c' | xargs tar -rf allcfiles.tar
```

[image]

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNUtar (which is common on Linux) then you can use the `--transform` option.

For example, with your current command we can see there's directories:

```
$ find . -name '*.c' | xargs tar -rf allcfiles.tar
$ tar tf allcfiles.tar                            
./b.c
./d/e.c
./a.c
```

With a transform we can avoid this:

```
$ find . -name '*.c' | xargs tar --transform='s!.*/!!' -rf allcfiles.tar
$ tar tf allcfiles.tar                                                  
b.c
e.c
a.c
```

The expression inside the `--transform` is a simple `sed` expression.  This one just strips off all directory components.

Comment: With a real `TAR` implementation, this gives error messages because the archive does not exist at the beginning. The original `UNIX TAR` does not deal with this at all, because it never creates an archive in `replace` mode. `star` warns because the archive at the beginning does not have a correct `EOF` marker. I recommend a modern tar like star with built in `find` and with `pax` like path substitution and not to use the `replace` mode.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am using macos. I tried ur answer but it does not work

Comment: If you're using macOS then you might want to change the tags; you added "linux" as a tag, and so I gave a Linux answer...

Comment: It works on linux. Thanks a lot. I need to run script on linux not macos. Sorry for not beeing clear.

Comment: Since we are going to rely on GNU features, it's probably worth mentioning the options to handle file names safely - `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0`. (Sure, newlines in real-world file names are extremely unlikely, but...).

Answer (score 1):

If your `find` implementation supports the `-execdir` option, you can `tar` the files without their directories like this:

```
find . -name '*.c' -type f -execdir tar rf $PWD/mytar.tar {} +
```

Just make sure the path to the tar file is an absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method that works using only POSIX compliant commands:

```
find . -name '*.c' | pax -w  -s ',.*/,,' > allcfiles.tar
```

If you like to use `tar rf archive ...`, you need to start with a correct **empty** archive at the beginning, since a real `tar` does not create the archive when in `replace` mode. To achieve this, you could first run this command to create an empty TAR archive:

```
printf "\000"| dd ibs=10k conv=sync > allcfiles.tar
```

By the way, I prefer this command:

```
star cf allcfiles.tar -s ',*/,,' -find . -name '*.c'
```

since this is the fastest method because `star` uses `libfind` and this needs to call `stat()` only once per file as the `stat` data from `libfind` is used by `star` to set up the file meta data in the archive.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am using macos. I tried ur answer but it does not work. I wonder if macos cannot do this at all.

Comment: Which command did you try and why did it fail? Since MacOS claims to be POSIX compliant, it needs to work with my POSIX compliant command.

Comment: @chenCrush: Given that the command works on FreeBSD and that MacOS has a FreeBSD userland, it is highly improbable that the command fails on MacOS.